# Is there a way to query objects inside objects in using JOSQL in java?

Tags: java, josql

I can query using JOSQL the current elements of the object. Is there a way to search the lists of objects that is returned by the query?. Lets say this will fetch a list of Car objects.

```
List <Person> search_list = new ArrayList<Person>();
for (Person pp: plist ){
    search_list.add(pp);
}


Query q = new Query();
q.parse("SELECT  cars from Person WHERE name=\"aname\"");
QueryResults execute = q.execute(search_list);
System.out.println(execute.getResults());
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @Andremoniy Lets say there is a set of person and each person may have one or more cars. the cars field in person class has a list of cars. the above query returns a list of Car object with properties like manufacturers, capacity etc. Is there a query to search through the Cars too? . I can only search through the direct properties of Person.